# Minimal API ASP.NET core: is it possible to get HTTP verb inside of derived FlatValidator?

Tags: c#, httpcontext

We want to try to increase performance in one microservice of our solution, that's why we have decided to try the [FlatValidator](https://github.com/belset/FlatValidator) in the part of the data validation. I'm new with such approach, at first glance it looks like very simple but I have to get an access to HttpContext into the derived class and it does not work.

```js
public record class RateRequest(Guid RateId, string Metadata);

public class RateRequestValidator : FlatValidator<RateRequest>
{
    public RateRequestValidator(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.Request.Method == HttpMethods.Post)
        {
            ValidIf(m => m.RateId == Guid.Empty, 
                    m => $"Bad HTTP method ({httpContext.Request.Method}).", 
                    m => m.RateId);
        }
        else if (httpContext.Request.Method == HttpMethods.Put)
        {
            ValidIf(m => m.RateId != Guid.Empty, 
                    m => $"Bad HTTP method ({httpContext.Request.Method}).", 
                    m => m.RateId);
        }
    }
}
```

But it gives me the error: System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: System.Validation.IFlatValidator`1[RateRequest] Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: RateRequestValidator'...

Please, help me to figure out this problem.

Comment: your github link is broken. I am guessing here but the error sounds like you are missing something in the dependency injection.

Comment: I think you need this library https://www.nuget.org/packages/FlatValidator.DependencyInjection, and look if you have to call any method at the startup.cs to register FlatValidation, try write `builder.Services.AddFlat....` and see what the autocomplete will give you

Comment: the docs say you need to add this `services.AddFlatValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());`

Comment: It seems you're not passing `HttpContext` into the validator. Try adding HTTP context accessor to your DI - `services.AddHttpContextAccessor()` and replace `HttpContext` in constructor with `IHttpContextAccessor`

Comment: @jeb, the link is working. But it is direct link - https://github.com/belset/FlatValidator

Comment: @ArthurEdgarov helped, thank you. 

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

public class RateRequestValidator : FlatValidator<RateRequest>
{
    public RateRequestValidator(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
       if (httpContextAccessor.HttpContext is HttpContext httpContext) {
         // ....
       }
    }
}

Comment: What's the question here? That package was only released last week and the repo already contains minimal API examples (filters). The only way you'd know about that package would be to work with the team. Have you checked the samples?

Answer (score 0):

Advice of @'Arthur Edgarov' was correct. Yes, the problem was not related to FlatValidator, the HttpContext can not be reached directly, only via IHttpContextAccessor.

```
// needs to register HttpContextAccessor
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddFlatValidatorsFromAssembly(typeof(RateRequestValidator).Assembly);

// ......

public record class RateRequest(Guid RateId, string Metadata);

public class RateRequestValidator : FlatValidator<RateRequest>
{
    // and pass IHttpContextAccessor as parameter instead of HttpContext
    public RateRequestValidator(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        if (httpContextAccessor.HttpContext is HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            if (httpContext.Request.Method == HttpMethods.Post)
            {
                ValidIf(m => m.RateId == Guid.Empty, 
                        m => $"Bad HTTP method ({httpContext.Request.Method}).", 
                        m => m.RateId);
            }
            else if (httpContext.Request.Method == HttpMethods.Put)
            {
                ErrorIf(m => m.RateId == Guid.Empty,
                        m => $"Bad HTTP method ({httpContext.Request.Method}).", 
                        m => m.RateId);
            }
        }
    }
}
```